# Unable to convert the data type VARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to change the data type `VARCHAR` to `INT`. I would appreciate your help.

```
CASE 
   WHEN [Worksheet].[Worksheet].[PLC Cd] IS NOT NULL
      THEN [Worksheet].[Worksheet].[PLC Cd]
      ELSE (IF ([Pool Number] = 0)
              THEN ([Worksheet].[Revenue Worksheet].[Account ID])
              ELSE (CAST([Pool Number], VARCHAR(7))))
END
```

- `Account_ID` data type is `Varchar`
- `Pool number` data type is `Int`

I do not want to use the cast as `varchar` as above mentioned. I would like to convert the ACCOUNT ID as `INT`.

ACCOUNT ID data format is: 500-201-001

Note: SQL Server issues a warning, due to the `CAST`:

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(varchar(7), [RPT_REVENUE_WKS].[POOL_NO], 0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

Comment: So... `500-201-001` is not numeric. Perhaps replace out those hyphens and then cast it `REPLACE(Account_ID, '-', '')`

Comment: CASE 
   WHEN [Worksheet].[Worksheet].[PLC Cd] IS NOT NULL
      THEN [Worksheet].[Worksheet].[PLC Cd]
      ELSE (IF ([Pool Number] = 0)
              THEN ([Worksheet].[Revenue Worksheet].CAST(REPLACE([Account ID],'-','')AS INT))
              ELSE (CAST([Pool Number], VARCHAR(7))))
END